# Call Reveal function for App Header

Tags: polymer

Is it possible to call the reveals function for app-header? The one that gets called when you scroll back up. I just want to play around with a possible idea.

For example:

```
_reveal: function() {
  this.$.header.reveals=true;
}

<app-header reveals>
  <app-toolbar>
    <div main-title>App name</div>
  </app-toolbar>
</app-header>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`reveals` is not a function. It's property of app-header (like variable). And it accepts only boolean values (true, false)

you can call all functions specified in documentation:
https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/app-header

There are also hidden (private) functions you can call but i don't recommend you to do it. To find them, you have to look into app-header.html file.

If you are looking for a function that handle `reveals` property it's propably in `_updateScrollState`

Comment: Thanks Kuba, I see those private functions. Seems there's a bit going on, and probably uses _transformHeader to do the slide effect. Probably better off writing my own.